# How to share or reshare posts in facebook page and groups in windows phone

Tags: facebook

Not able to share and re-share posts in pages and groups

Comment: How are you trying to do this? Are you using their app, their web interfface from IE, or something else?

Comment: I am using Facebook app in mobile. Sometimes IE also

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook app on Windows phone does not allow you to share post to a group or friends.
The feature you ask for is not present in the Facebook app for Windows.